# Loading spring-cloud-consul properties from default Environment

Tags: spring, properties, configuration, spring-cloud, consul

Why spring-cloud-consul is not loading consul specific properties from application.properties file?

Is there any way to allow spring to load this consul properties from application.properties or from any other custom property file not from bootstrap.properties?

Answer (score 1):

No, if you're using consul config, the consul connection information must be in `bootstrap.yml`.